# Regular Expression needed

Tags: c#, regex

Anyone please suggest for replacing `number)` and should not replace the `(number)`

Example:

```
String c= "hi im 12) ram from 45) us and my phn num is (405-656565656)"
```

Output required:

```
hi im ram from us and my my phn num is (405-656565656)
```

Comment: What did you try and what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the best solution but it works on your string. Regex: `\s[0-9]*\)`
It checks

```
 12)
 45)
```

But not

```
as45)
fd21)
```

Answer (score 0):

if length is only 2 digits this will find the field.

```
[^\d]\d[2]\)
```

But my guess is that you know the "variable" name? Since you need to replace it with a certain value. So why not simply do these?

In .NET regex:

For country

```
[^\d](?<country>45\))
```

For name

```
[^\d]<?<name>12\))
```